# Using a method in Objective-C cocoa

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, uitextfield, ibaction

I'm having trouble with something very basic. I want to call this action:

```
- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {
    self.userName = self.textField.text;

    NSString *nameString = self.userName;
    if ([nameString length]==0) {
        nameString = @"World";

    }
    NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@!", nameString];
    self.label.text = greeting;

}
```

When the user presses return after entering text in the text field. This is what I have:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField{
    if (theTextField == self.textField) {
        [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
        [changeGreeting];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I'm not sure what to put where it says "changeGreeting." Think I'm missing the concept here. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. Try this:

```
[self changeGreeting:self];
```

In Objective-C the syntax for sending messages (calling functions) is like this:

```
[receiver message];
```

Since you implement the `changeGreeting:` method in the same class as you're calling it from, the receiver will be `self`. As the parameter (sender) you usually pass the object that sends the message, but since you don't use it in your implementation of `changeGreeting:` it doesn't really matter what you pass there.

Answer (score 1):

you called the changeGreeting function in wrong way

you should call it like

```
[self changeGreeting:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to track something from the textField then

```
[self changeGreeting:theTextField];
```

the sender will get theTextField as parameter if you need some processing on based on the textField.